# Use JSON value from Zabbix item in two separate instances

Tags: zabbix

I have a Zabbix item named `Corrupt Sessions`, that calls a custom check (`UserParameter`) with the key `corrupt_sessions`. The output of this check is a JSON list.

Say something like:

```json
["abc", "def", "ghi"]
```

I want to do two things with the result of this item:

- Count the number of corrupt sessions
- Be able to make a textual list of all corrupt sessions (say something like: `Corrupt session IDs: abc, def, ghi`), whenever the number of corrupt sessions increases above some threshold.

The first thing I was able to do using a JSONPath preprocessing step inside the `Corrupt Sessions` item, with a `$.length()` parameter. And this works nicely, I get the number of corrupt sessions.

However, how can I use the same JSON output of this item to come up with the list? This custom check is quite intensive performance wise, therefore I want to avoid calling it twice.

Although, when I tried creating a new item with the same key `corrupt_sessions`, I got an error stating:

```
An item with key "corrupt_sessions" already exists on the template "XYZ".
```

Now, I can cheat a little and use `corrupt_sessions[]` as the key, but the error indicates to me that there should be a better way of re-using the output of the item (to avoid an expensive recheck) for a separate JSONPath preprocessor. (Note that the textual list would only be necessary when the corrupt session count reaches a certain threshold.)

How would one go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need the list in the alert message.

You can create a dependent item, and apply `$.length()` to it. This way you call the custom check one time, but you get two items on Zabbix. Then in the trigger, you will check `last(dependent_item)>0 and length(master_item)>0`: this way you can reference the list content as `{ITEM.LASTVALUE2}` in the notification.

See

- https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/dependent_items
- https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/appendix/macros/supported_by_location#triggers